# ServerError unknown error: cannot get automation extensionfrom unknown error

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

My wdio configuration file

```
      args: [
            '--enable-automation',
            '--start-maximized',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--test-type',
            '--disable-infobars',
            '--test-type=browser',
          ],
```

I have such error.

```
30 passing (191.50s)
3 pending
1 failing

1) [p] starts stage for students:
unknown error: cannot get automation extensionfrom unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
running
Error: unknown error: cannot get automation extensionfrom unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
    at new ErrorHandler.RuntimeError (node_modules/webdriverio/lib/utils/ErrorHandler.js:93:12)
    at Request._callback (node_modules/webdriverio/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js:59:33)
    at Request.self.callback (node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/request/request.js:373:22)
    at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/request/request.js:1318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/request/request.js:1266:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)




Exited with code 1
```

Chrome last stable version from official Google repository

webdriver last version 2.30

Comment: I've tested with your `wdio.config.js` `chromeOptions` and chromedriver v2.30, but I have all passing tests. So I'm sure that's something else. By the way, your run has **exit code 1** (failure) cause of the failing/pending tests, or because of your error? What's with the passing tests?